# Is it possible to use an Xbox One and 360 controller at the same time in PC games?

Tags: xbox-360, pc, controllers, xbox-one

I own an Xbox 360 controller. I'd like to play some fighting games (Street Fighter, Mortal Kombat, Injustice, Dead or Alive) against friends locally on my PC. So I have to get another controller. Now I was thinking about getting an Xbox One controller, because people say the digital pad (often used in fighting games) of the Xbox One controller is better than the digital pad of the Xbox 360 controller. Is it possible to use both the One and 360 controller at the same time (e.g. player 1 uses One controller, player 2 uses 360 controller) in games without any problems? Or are they using different versions of XInput which could maybe cause problems?

Answer (score 5):

I haven't tried it but I have both a 360 and an Xbox One pad.

They show up as two different controllers, so I don't see why it shouldn't work.

Here is what it looks like under Windows 7.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The answer is **YES**.

I've personally played games with multiple controllers connected, an XONE and an X360 to be exact.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. I have an old wireless Xbox 360 connected to PC with the USB adapter, and another Xbox One controller also wireless but with Bluetooth.

Works just fine under Windows 10 (haven't tried in Windows 7).